# Generate tests for all the classes from a directory

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have a directoy structure, and all the classes of the business logic are placed in the app_dir/lib/ directory. I would like to generate unit tests for all the classes from this lib/ folder.

The problem is, that I haven't found any option to specify the source directory, only the  source file:

from app_dir:

```
$ phpunit --skeleton-class lib/
Error: "lib/.php" could not be opened.
```

Is it the only solution to write my own php script, which iterates through the /lib folder
and calls the skeleton generator for every file found? And how can I specify the output folder, where all the generated test files are placed?

Comment: I'd suggest just using something like: `find lib -type f -name '*.php' -exec 'phpunit --skeleton-class {} ;'`

Answer (score 2):

To generate skeleton tests, you want `--skeleton-test` not `--skeleton-class`. This will extract the filename without the extension and pass it to phpunit.

```
for file in *.php; do phpunit --skeleton-test "${file%.*}"; done;
```

I have no idea how to change the output directory which you would need if you want to run the command multiple times. I suppose a better one-liner would only select files not ending with "Test.php".

Answer (score 0):

From Sebastian Bergmann's blog:

> As of changeset 2764, **PHPUnit 3.3**'s
>   command-line test runner accepts a
>   directory as its argument.
>
> Given a directory, the test runner
>   will recursively scan the directory
>   for *Test.php files, build a test
>   suite out of the *Test classes, and
>   run it.

With PHPUnit >= 3.3 you should be able to execute just:

```
phpunit lib
```

Comment: Nope, that's not what he asked for. He wants to generate test stubs for his existing classes.